# ionic2 storage not working properly in my android phone

Tags: ionic2

I have followed Ionic storage tutorial in 
It works in my browser. But in my testing device it not working.
Its mean after I closed the app in device and re-lunch it the stored values are gone.
But in browser It works properly.

Comment: I have followed Ionic storage tutorial in ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage –

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. After testing and research I found out that the polyfills.js and cordova.js script import where somehow causing this issue.

I solved it by importing the *build/pollyfills.js* **BEFORE** the *cordova.js* in the head tag of the *index.html* file.

Hope this helps.

```
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```